# Patterns for mapping error key to custom message in Java

Tags: java, exception

I would like to know if there are any recommended patterns for errorKey -> errorMessage look up? I am trying to improve my exception handling techniques and would be grateful for some ideas.

I am using some third party software and when an exception occurs they return an error key in the format THIRD_PARTY_ERROR_KEY. This maps to some awful message that the user should not see. I think I could use a static class that takes the key and looks up the message from a resource bundle but I would like some recommendations on some nice pattern to do this.

I am using Spring 2.5.6 and thought there might be something sexier that I could do.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of [Spring MessageSource](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/basic-webapp-internationalization-message-resource.html)?  I think that's the ticket here.  Look at the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource).

Comment: Yeah was skirting around that. Cheers.

Comment: came here to suggest JDK ResourceBundle, which Spring's MessageSource basically wraps - so I second this suggestion